# Powershell/ How can I remove @{ } from my CSV

Tags: powershell

I have code like this:

```
.
.
.
$s=$csv|select -ExpandProperty links

$m=$s|select hooks

$m

$m|Export-Csv C:\ooo.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

When I execute this code, it prints:

```
hooks                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
-----                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
@{href=https://yahoo.com/users/helloworld/hooks}
```

When I export this to CSV, it shows exactly like this, but I would like to take @{} out; I would like to show only like this:

```
href=https://yahoo.com/users/helloworld/hooks
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually this stuff can be gotten rid of as you import into a variable. you can use the below to replace it after. This says for each string in the variable m, replace @, }, and { with ""(nothing)

$m | %{$newvar += $_ -replace "@","" -replace "}","" -replace "{",""}

$newvar | export-csv -notypeinformation .....

Comment: PS C:\Users\user1> $m | %{$_ -replace "@","" -replace "}","" -replace "{",""}
href=https://yahoo.com/users/helloworld/hooks

Answer (score 1):

could be that `hooks` is a collection which in that case must be converted to a string for `export-csv`.

```
$m = ($csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty links).hooks -join ';'
$m | Export-Csv .................
```